# Window Open from jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make this more secure and safe:

- Strip unsafe characters from title
- Prevent undefined errors

Code so far:

```
// Open HREF in popup window
$('.external').bind('click', function () {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var title = ($(this).attr("data-popup-title")) ? $(this).attr("data-popup-title") : $(this).attr("title");
    var image = $(this).attr("data-popup-image");
    var width = ($(this).attr("data-popup-width")) ? $(this).attr("data-popup-width") : '626';
    var height = ($(this).attr("data-popup-height")) ? $(this).attr("data-popup-height") : '436';
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=' + title + '&amp;p[url]=' + url + '&amp;&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width='+width+',height='+height);
    return false;
});
```

Also is it best practice to `return false` or use the `preventDefault()`?

Comment: This isn't security. There is nothing secure about stripping data from tags in JavaScript. If somebody has managed to inject script into the `title` attribute of a link, they have the ability to execute that code long before your handler comes along and opens a popup window. There is really no point to doing what you're doing. Also, please only post one question per question.

Comment: Ok maybe secure not the right word.

Comment: But I still want to have 1 on click function instead of hard coding the window.open into every a

Comment: That's fine, using `.external` and binding click handlers is fine. But your question is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about best-practices, `preventDefault()` and `return false` do *different things*. Returning false prevents the event from bubbling up through other handlers, while `preventDefault` simply prevents the default "click" action (typically following the href of the link) from occurring after all other event handlers have run.